# Store GitLab repositories on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab

Is there a possibility to config GitLab so it can keep repositories on S3?
I've found aws.yml and configured it, but what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping repos on S3 is not a good idea. It's better to create dedicated EBS volume for repo storage.

UPDATE 11.04.2019:

Some time ago I've read that S3 is not a good place to keep Git repos due to the fact that .git tree generates a lot of objects stored in storages like S3.

Cannot find the docs now, but things had changed and many of you and also AWS is pointing out that Git repos on S3 are just fine.

For Gitlab, you can find a neat table comparing storage services:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html#hashed-storage-coverage

Comment: And what is your reason for this assessment?

Comment: I would be interested in any 2024 benchmark to compare S3 vs EBS storage for this use case if any of you have a link to an article.